# Issues with dynamic height for UITableViewCell with UIStackView while scrolling up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with cells with dynamic heights. Inside each cell, I have an image view and a group of 4 labels in a vertical stack view. When I first load the tableview, the cells look fine and the height is calculated correctly. This is also true for the cells that load after scrolling downwards. However, as soon as I scroll up, the height of the cell becomes huge (bigger than the entire screen).

Im not sure why this happens only when I scroll up.

[tableview after initial loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQkR0.png)

[tableview after scrolling upwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuZdK.png)

Comment: Are you assign height from "heightForRowAt indexPath" of UITableView delegate method or from storyboard?

Comment: are you setting any height/constraint programatically?

Comment: i assigned the rowheight of the tableview to UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimatedRowHeight to 100

Comment: can you provide the screenshot's how it looks before and after scrolling.

Comment: i have added the screen shots. Do you think it has something to do with my stackview configuration? I set it to equal spacing.

Comment: i have figured out the problem! I set the spacing parameter to a value not 0 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I set the spacing parameter for UIStackView to a value not 0 and it worked!